# How to configure fluent api?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I need help configuring the fluent api to return the correct link for each user type.

The table is filled like this:

[image]

The rule is:

```
If cGarage.UserType == 1 then cGarage.UserID = cPerson1.Id
If cGarage.UserType == 2 then cGarage.UserID = cPerson2.Id 
If cGarage.UserType == 3 then cGarage.UserID = cCar1.Id
If cGarage.UserType == 4 then cGarage.UserID = cCar2.Id
```

My classes:

```
public class Garage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int UserType { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public cPerson1 Person1 { get; set; }
    public cPerson2 Person2 { get; set; }
    public cCar1 Car1  { get; set; }
    public cCar2 Car2 { get; set; }   
    
}

public class Person1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public List<Garage> Garages { get; } = new();
}

public class Person2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public List<Garage> Garages { get; } = new();
}

public class Car1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public List<Garage> Garages { get; } = new();
}

public class Car2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public List<Garage> Garages { get; } = new();
    
}
```

I need to configure the relationships. The UserType field will be essential to define which table the EF will refer to, but I don't know how to inform it. Can you help me?

```
modelBuilder
.Entity<Person1>()
.HasMany(u => u.Garages)
.WithOne(c => c.Person1)
.HasForeignKey(h => h.UserID);
```

Thanks

Comment: You want for Garage if ```UserType == 1``` to join with Person1 and if ```UserType == 2``` to join with Person2 ?

Comment: Exactly. How to make?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I don't think it can be done in one Linq query. Why do you need 2 absolutely identical classes ?